# PHP PDO Binding Time Variables for Postgresql Query

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Folks, I'm having trouble debugging this. Please note that after testing the query in Elephant Postgresql, I can verify the query works when a string literal is handed over in the interval cast:

```
function get_most_popular_posts($dbh, $count = 10, $from = 0) {

try{
$option = strval($from);
$newfrom = $option.' seconds';
//var_dump($from);
$sql = 'WITH top_voted AS(
        SELECT COUNT(post_id), post_id FROM VotedBy GROUP BY post_id
        ), res AS (SELECT id AS pid, author AS username, title, 
        body AS content, posted AS time,
        coordX AS coorX, coordY AS coorY, COUNT FROM Posts, top_voted
        WHERE Posts.id = top_voted.post_id AND posted >= (current_timestamp - interval :newfrom))
        SELECT pid, username, title, content, time, coorx, coory FROM res ORDER BY COUNT DESC, time DESC LIMIT :count;';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':count', $count);
$stmt->bindParam(':newfrom', $newfrom);
$stmt->execute(); 
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//var_dump($stmt);
//var_dump($result);
//var_dump($newfrom);
```

Please help. Var_dumping the bound variable suggests that the concatenation works.

Comment: You cannot use the literal syntax (e.g. `typename 'value'`) with bound parameters. Use casting instead (e.g. `CAST(:boundvar AS typename)`).

Comment: AFAIK, if you don't set the type of parameter, it'll be parsed as string. I think there have to be a integer. As poz said, cast can be as well.